# Creating numeric variable based on string intersection in R

Tags: r, string

I'm attempting to create a numeric variable based on the intersection of strings with R's dplyr package.
I have a list of columns containing codes for thousands of individuals who made purchases at an auto dealership. The codes can represent a purchase of a car, internal parts for a car, or items for the exterior of a car. I want to denote codes identified as a car purchase with 2, items for the interior of a car with 1, and items for the exterior of a car with 0. If the customer purchased a car, I want the column LargestPurchase = 2; if the customer didn't buy a car but bought an interior component, I would like the column LargestPurchase = 1; and if the customer did not buy a car or interior component I would like the column LargestPurchase = 0.

The codes for a car purchase are located in a separate data frame with column CarCodes, and the codes for the interior components of a car are located in a separate data frame with column InteriorCodes. Each contain thousands of codes.

The data for the customers would look like the following (called customers):

```
Customer1     PurchaseCode1    PurchaseCode2    PurchaseCode3
001           STW387           K987             W9333
002           AZ326            CP993            EN499
003           BKY98            A0091            C2001
```

Example:

```
df1$CarCodes = c('STW387', 'W9333')
df2$InteriorCodes = c('K987', 'AZ326')

Customer1     PurchaseCode1    PurchaseCode2    PurchaseCode3   LargestPurchase 
001           STW387           K987             W9333           2
002           AZ326            CP993            EN499           1
003           BKY98            A0091            C2001           0
```

I attempted to use the following ifelse function with mutate, but it does not seem to work with strings:

```
      customers <- customers %>% mutate(LargestPurchase = 
    (ifelse(intersect(customers$PurchaseCode1, df1$CarCodes) == TRUE | 
intersect(customers$PurchaseCode2, df1$CarCodes) | 
intersect(customers$PurchaseCode3, df1$CarCodes), 2, ifelse( 
intersect(customers$PurchaseCode1, df2$InteriorCodes) == TRUE | 
intersect(customers$PurchaseCode2, df2$InteriorCodes) == TRUE |
intersect(customers$PurchaseCode3, df3$InteriorCodes) == TRUE, 1, 0)))
```

Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` version

```
CarCodes = c('STW387', 'W9333')
InteriorCodes = c('K987', 'AZ326')

data.frame(customer = c(001, 002, 003),
           code1 = c('STW387', 'AZ326', 'BKY98'),
           code2 = c('K987', 'CP993', 'A0091'),
           code3 = c('W9333', 'EN499', 'C2001')) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -customer) %>% 
  mutate(purchase = case_when(value %in% CarCodes ~ 2,
                              value %in% InteriorCodes ~ 1,
                              TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>% 
  summarise(largest_purchase = max(purchase))
```

Answer (score 1):

Determine if either the `CarCodes` or `InteriorCodes` are contained and then use the max value.

```
c2 <- apply(df3[,-1], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x %in% df2$InteriorCodes), 1, 0))
c1 <- apply(df3[,-1], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x %in% df1$CarCodes), 2, 0))
df3$LargestPurchase <- pmax(c1, c2)

  Customer1 PurchaseCode1 PurchaseCode2 PurchaseCode3 LargestPurchase
1         1        STW387          K987         W9333               2
2         2         AZ326         CP993         EN499               1
3         3         BKY98         A0091         C2001               0
```